# How to save a big collection from mongo into a text file with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I need to save the records value from a mongodb collection into a text file, but it's a big collection with over 8 million of records.
The collection has two fields:
id and description, the description is a large text.

Comment: Not going to write the whole algorithm for you, but in general you're going to have to use a buffer and file system (fs module) to write the data from the db to a file. I suggest taking a look at this:

https://stackabuse.com/writing-to-files-in-node-js/

And this:

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Using a stream will help you avoid crushing your RAM during the write.

Comment: Thanks, i don't need all the code just clues to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export directly the records from a collection to a json or csv file using [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

> mongoexport --host {host_name} --username {user_name} --password {password} --db {database_name} --collection {collection_name} --out {output_file}

Where:

- --host is an optional parameter that specifies the remote server Mongo database instance
- --username and --password are the optional parameters that specify the authentication details of a user
- --db specifies the database name
- --collection specifies the collection name
- --out specifies the path of the output file. If this is not specified, the result is displayed on the console

Comment: To hell with my method, do this!